# VS2015 EDI very slow with XAML

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015

I'm facing performance issues when editing xaml files (views, styles, app.xaml, ...) in Visual Studio 2015.

If a xaml file is open I got a really nasty delay when typing or scrolling, even in other files.  Also my CPU goes up and IntelliSense is not loaded.  When I close all xaml files then everything just go back to normal performance, also in other files like .cs or .resw.

After a while I got an error that say "*An exception has been encounterd.  This may be caused by an extenstion*".  And yes, I've looked in the ActivityLog.xml file, but I couldn't figure it out.  There where 2 errors, 1 with a source of "*ClientRights (Client rights determined)*" and 1 with "*Editor or Editor Extension (System.NullReferenceException)*"

I'm running Windows Version 1607 (OS Build 14393.222) and Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

I have the feeling that it all started when I installed update 3, not quite sure if that has something to do with it, it's been a while when I've been in a xaml project (in this case UWP).
It must be something to do with the XAML designer, although I disabled it.

These are the steps I've already tried:

- Disable extenstions (some couldn't be disabled)
- Uninstalled Resharper
- New install of vs2015 Update 3
- Found on stackoverflow ([Visual Studio 2015 is extremely slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34395686/visual-studio-2015-extremely-slow)):

  - Disable XMAL designer (Options > XAML Designer - uncheck "Enable XAML Designer")
  - Disable solution analysis (Options > C# > Advanced - uncheck "Enable full solution analysis")
  - Disable CodeLens (Options > Text Editor > All languages - uncheck "Enable CodeLens")
- Clear asp.net caches

Anyone facing the same problem?  Any help would be very appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New install of vs2015 didn't help.

Fresh install of win10 + vs2015 did the job :-( 
Lost many hours but back running!