# Struggling with visual studio 2017 and ssis

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 professional latest update and latest update of ssdt. Now I struggle very much with the Developer environment.

In my vs solution I have 2 SQL projects,1 SSIS project and 1 SSAS tabular. When I open the solution I can’t almost do anything before Visual Studio is freezing or going down and is restarting. IT is especially the SSIS project this is happening on.

I have used severdig days to find out a way out of this. For instance if I open a data flow task the solution is freezing in a state like IT is saving. IT can be like this until I must end the vs task. I really don’t know what do come out of this. Everything have Worked smoothly but now I don’t come any way.

My computer should have 16 GB memory. Maybe the versions of Visual Studio and SSDT I have don’t fit together. Should I do a complete reinstall on my machine or is there an azure virtual machine image with vs2017 and ssdt? Or do any of know that docker have Visual Studio 2017 ssdt image ?

One more thing I tried to downgrade ssis 2017 to SSIS 2014. Same problem here freezing like storing for hours. Sometime It manager to change and the project is stored. But suddenly IT crashes and when the solution is up again IT is back on SSIS 2017. Very frustrating

Any ideas?

Comment: Once the SSIS project is open, under the SSIS menu - check Work Offline. Save All, close the solution and then reopen - does it go faster? https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymITF.png

Comment: Well I have experienced what you mentioned and IT is alsi very frustrating. But this is different. One of two things is happening either some seconds like storing and pang. Vs crashes and restarts or second IT waits forever until I had to kill the process myself. Both are terrible. I need to find a way around this before I am smashing the computer.

Comment: So does Work Offline resolve the issue?

Comment: It seems that you are on a resource constrained machine e.g. i3 CPU, slow rotating HDD not SSD, slow memory. I thus suggest to try lean, only work with one project at a time. It'd be good to profile what takes so much resources. At times these are merely various add-ons to the Visual Studio as tools, etc.

Comment: My PC is running on i7 professor and 32 GB ram. This has worked before I upgrqded to latest version of vs 2017.

Comment: @GeirForsmo this is a common issue of Visual Studio 2017, for me i uninstall it and installed 2015 version. If you search in visual studio developer community website you will find a lot of similar issue recorded

Comment: @GeirForsmo after checking the answer below, it contains many link from the developer community

Answer (score 1):

I think there are 2 possible causes for this issue:

**(1) Third party extensions (add-ins)**

The issue may be caused by some added extensions to the visual studio, try to run visual studio in safe mode with the current command (it will disable all third party extensions):

```
devenv.exe /safemode
```

**(2) Data validation**

If you are designing the package in online mode, there are some data validation that are executed when you open the project, this process can cause freezing the ssis designer in many cases such as working with huge volume of data, invalid data sources ...

Try change the design mode to Offline, in the menu strip:

> SSIS >> Work Offline

---

## Update 1

After searching it looks like this is an issue that can occur with Visual studio 2017:

- [Visual Studio 2017 increadibly slow and laggy](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/43364/visual-studio-2017-increadibly-slow-and-laggy.html)
- [VS2017 RC1 - Editor suddenly lagging/slow/bogs down](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/6047/vs2017-rc1-editor-suddenly-laggingslowbogs-down.html)
- [VS2017 working very slow during ASP.NET debugging](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/41708/vs2017-working-very-slow.html)

The links above contains helpful discussions and a lot of suggestions.

Also, you might check the following answer it may give you some insights:

- [Visual Studio 2017 is too slow during building and debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42877071/visual-studio-2017-is-too-slow-during-building-and-debugging)

In addition, check the following Microsoft documentation:

- [Optimize Visual Studio performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/optimize-visual-studio-performance?view=vs-2017)

Comment: Thanks i will try your advice. I know the extensions can  slow things down. But IT must be something with the latest version of vs. IT has worked before

Comment: @GeirForsmo  Check that the `TargetServerVersion` of the project is adequate https://zappysys.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001710233-How-to-change-TargetServerVersion-of-my-SSIS-Project