# VS2015 - executable run very slow

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

***Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise has worked great for many months.  Now it's running very slow, and I can't figure out why.***

Even the simpliest "hello world" console applications takes 5 minutes to run within Visual Studio.  It will build quickly (~1 sec). When I run the executable from the "bin" folder (i.e., command line), it also runs quickly (~1 sec).  But, when I run it from within Visual Studio it takes on the order of 5 minutes to run.

This is a managed workstation, so I have a lingering feeling something happened in the background.

*Things I've tried include:*

- Restart the computer
- Same issue on another user's machine in my office.
- Review the machine CPU and memory usage, which never comes close to the limits
- Debug vs. Release mode does not seem to make a difference
- Created the simpliest program possible, a "hello world" console application
- Project properties > Debug > Enable Debuggers > Enable the Visual Studio hosting process (toggled); no difference
- No breakpoints are set
- Tools->Options and search for "Symbols". Uncheck "Microsoft Symbol Servers".

**Anyone have ideas on how to fix or troubleshoot?**
**Conclusion:**  I had VS2017 installed side-by-side with VS2015.  VS2017 works; VS2015 does not.  (They did a Microsoft Office upgrade, which I think conflicted with my VS install.)

Comment: Slow running can be caused by many factors. One of these factor is conditional breakpoint. But are you saying, that even "Hello world" program runs slow? Then the reason must be some other factor.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34395686/visual-studio-2015-is-extremely-slow

Comment: Build the simplest possible console app. Build it. Run it from Visual Studio debugger. How long does it take to run (is that 5 minutes)? Run it directly (from the command line not Visual Studio). How long does it take to run (is that 1 second)?

Comment: If you take the exact same project, onto a co-worker's PC, does it have the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to send them feedback. There are rolling perf tests running in VS, but I imagine nobody looks at VS 2015.

Can't you install to VS 2017? They work pretty well side by side. In fact, I suggest you install VS 2017 Preview - I'm using it and it is remarkably stable (in the past, preview editions of VS were crashing all the time).

Comment: Except the whole "Enterprise" part of it.  OP may very well NOT have proper licensing for 2017, or may be tied to 2015 for other reasons.

Comment: @user2366842 - true, but most organizations purchase Enterprise through an MSDN subscription, so he should have access to all versions of VS. If this isn't the case, there aren't many features in Enterprise anyway (Intellitrace being the notable one). The important thing is that they run side by side - there a was a lot of testing done to ensure SxS scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Could be anything, but lately I had trouble with using their symbol servers. Everything would run really slow when started from Visual Studio.

Open Tools->Options and search for "Symbols". Uncheck "Microsoft Symbol Servers".